# set youtube v3 channel banner image, through ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, youtube, google-api, google-api-client

I am able to upload the image, to youtube channel arts.

This is the ruby script i have

https://gist.github.com/anbublacky/ff76b56642613bfe3066

I am unable to set the uploaded image as banner

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/update

They have given python example, where i don know what this function does

```
image_url = resumable_upload(insert_request)
```

they are assinging image url to

```
channel_brandingSettings["image"]["bannerExternalUrl"] = banner_url
```

and again don know how to convert this to ruby

```
channels_update_response = youtube.channels().update(
  part='brandingSettings',
  body=dict(
    brandingSettings=channel_brandingSettings,
    id = channels_response["items"][0]["id"]
  )).execute()
```

So mainly im unable to set the uploaded image as banner through google api using ruby

## EDIT

This is what im trying to set banner image, still not working(tried from python example https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/update)

```
banner_url = JSON.parse(image_insert_response.body)["url"]
channel_list_res["items"][0]["brandingSettings"]["image"]["bannerExternalUrl"] = []
channel_brandingSettings = channel_list_res["items"][0]["brandingSettings"]
channel_brandingSettings["image"]["bannerExternalUrl"] = banner_url

channels_update_response = client.execute!(
    :api_method => youtube.channels.update,
    :parameters => {    
        :part => 'brandingSettings',
    },

    :body => {
        :brandingSettings => channel_brandingSettings,
        :id => channel_list_res['items'][0]['id']
 })
```

i'm getting the following error

undefined method `bytesize' for #

Comment: Rather than try to reverse-engineer a python library, and replicate its function in Ruby, why don't you just use a Ruby gem, eg https://rubygems.org/gems/youtube/versions/0.8.6

Comment: currently google api version is v3 and the youtube gem uses version2 i think, in the gem default api path is //api2_rest and in ruby doc there is no update youtube banner section

Comment: I think this gem can help me, https://github.com/Fullscreen/yt, will update once i find a solution

Comment: There also no document about channel banner